# Using javascript in offline Page

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create my own starting website. Its just a simple, local stored HTML document with some of my favourite Links.

Now, I want to load / run an external javascript code like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://javascript.com/javascript.js"></script>
```

This is for a small widget but doesn't seem to work. I uploaded the site then on a server and the widget showed up.

So, is it necessary to run a server (like apache or node.js) to compile the javascript or is there any other easier possibility?

Comment: By offline, do you mean without an internet connection? Or just not hosting the page on a server?

Comment: bro download it and save at local and use as much as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a JavaScript file locally, then implement file scheme `file://` in the URL value of the `src` attribute of your `<script>` tag, along with a path to your JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:/localjavascript.js"></script>
```